# elasticsearch nest 2 add to bool query dynamically

Tags: c#-4.0, elasticsearch, nest

I have a boolean query that I want to add dynamically to using the object intializer syntax but I am having trouble doing so. Basically, I have 5 stages of checking parameters, and if they exist they get added to the boolquery. Here's what I am trying to do (obviously doesn't work):

```
SomeBoolQuery.Must.ToList().Add(someQueryContainer);
```

How can I make the above work so that I can dynamically add queries to the BoolQuery? No, I can't do it via this:

```
SomeBoolQuery.Must = new QueryContainer[] {query1, query2};
```

Because I don't know how many queries I am going to have and I can't add them all at once. I need a dynamic solution.

I was thinking maybe this:

```
SomeBoolQueryContainer &= someQuery;
```

and then at the end:

```
SomeBoolQuery.Must = new QueryContainer[] {someBoolQueryContainer};
```

But that seems a little redundant to say the least. Any ideas?

EDIT: The last option tried above doesn't seem to work. not returning any results.

Answer (score 1):

Adding bool query dynamically using Fluent API :

```
        ElasticQueryContainer elasticQueryContainer = GetSearchQuery(searchRequest);
        var response = client.Search<IDocument>(s1 => s1
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(bq => bq
                        .Should(elasticQueryContainer.orQuery.ToArray())
                        .Must(elasticQueryContainer.andQuery.ToArray())
                        .MustNot(elasticQueryContainer.notQuery.ToArray())

                        )));


public class ElasticQueryContainer
{
    public List<QueryContainer> orQuery { get; set; }
    public List<QueryContainer> andQuery { get; set; }
    public List<QueryContainer> notQuery { get; set; }
    public ElasticQueryContainer()
    {
        orQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();
        andQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();
        notQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();
    }
}

public ElasticQueryContainer GetSearchQuery(SearchRequest searchRequest )
{
 //...Populate ElasticQueryContainer : orQuery, andQuery, notQuery dynamically
var elasticQueryContainer = new ElasticQueryContainer();
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRequest.FullTextSearch))
        {
            elasticQueryContainer.andQuery.Add(new QueryStringQuery
            {
                Query = searchRequest.FullTextSearch.ToLower(),
                DefaultOperator = searchRequest.FullTextOperator == SearchEnums.FullTextSearchOperator.AND ? Operator.And : Operator.Or 
            });
        }
}
```

The SearchRequest is a class having properties which has to be searched.

```
public class SearchRequest
{

    public String FullTextSearch { get; set; }

    public SearchEnums.FullTextSearchOperator FullTextOperator { get; set; }

}
```

For Object intializer syntax, you can use it this way :

```
new BoolQuery()
{
MustNot = elasticQueryContainer.notQuery.ToArray(),
Should = elasticQueryContainer.orQuery.ToArray(),
Must = elasticQueryContainer.andQuery.ToArray()
};
```

You can also refer to : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/bool-query-usage.html